A list of quotes from ChaZaL about astronomy
I am learning some rudimentary astronomy at the moment. I am limiting myself to phenomena that can be observed with the naked eye. My aim is to get a complete understanding of the motion of the seven walking stars and also the fixed stars from the vantage point of somebody potentially anywhere in this world. This is not to say I am assuming a geocentric model. It's just that given I am hear on the ground and not in space I am more interested in what I can expect to see from here rather than some point in outer space.
Does anyone know of an exhaustive list of quotes from ChaZaL that could help me deduce their understanding of these matters?

Dunno about that specifically but check out אוצר האגדה from mossad harav kook entry כוכבים ומזלות for all related maamarei chazal

Nothing in the Talmud indicates that the Talmudic sages had any tradition about astronomy, moreover, in Psochim 94 we see an encounter where they changed their ancient views (https://pursuingveritas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/ancient-hebrew-view-of-universe.png) and [on the spot] adopted Hellenistic cosmology. Moreover, Rambam in Hilchos Hiddush Hachodesh says explicitly that the calculations of Moon phases were adopted from the Chaldeans and Babylonians".

I really like this question. I just question the word "astronomy" slightly. Torah sources will generally be in the ballpark of "astrology" rather than astronomy (the two overlap quite a bit, but unsticking one from the other might be tough), although the halachot of the calendar will be more focussed on the astronomical side of things. Perhaps get a good work on these halachos?

@RabbiKaii It is more about cosmology. It is worth mentioning that the sages use exegesis, rather than empirical research, they read Biblical verses and try to interpret them creatively. See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.94b.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Kuzari 2:64, 66 on science of Sanhedrin; Bava Metzia 85B Shmuel's syringe, Eruvin 43B Rabbon Gamliels telescope and math; Bechorot 8B Rabbi Yehoshua declaring that Chazal's science is better than the non-Jews'; Vayikra Rabba 19:1 Rabbi Asi's experiments and Rabbi R Shimon Ben Chalafta's in Chullin 57B, R Yishmael's in ibid 30B... etc

See the discussion of the new month in Rosh Hashana.
